# Cloud Firestore not returning data when used inside chrome extension

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use firestore inside a chrome extension and I set everything up following some docs I found through google.

In my manifest.json file I added this:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com https://*.firebaseio.com; object-src 'self'"
```

And inside a html file where I want to use firestore, I'm including these:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

In that same html file, I'm including another js file which has the following code:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "xxx",
    databaseURL: "xxx",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx"
  };

firebase.initializeApp(config);

firebase.firestore().collection('users').onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.docs);
});
```

The problem is that `snapshot.docs` is always an empty array despite some data actually existing. There are no errors or warnings. It just returns an empty array.

Comment: Let me know if you find any workaround of using firestore inside chrome extension

Comment: @kirtan403 I was able to get it working without changing anything from what I posted above. It's just that snapshot.docs returns data only if you query the docs at the leaf nodes. Or else it returns an empty array.

Comment: So cloud firestore works from the extension. That's great news. Thanks for the update